# Text instead of images

Tags: firefox, images

Go to the following page, [Yahoo Answers](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20141224050937AAPk8VP) There's a screenshot of the problem by the question owner. When I click on the image to see it, [image: This is what I got], a window with so many characters and which don't make any sense. I am using firefox latest update. But this problem doesn't exist in Torch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Response headers include:

`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

This is a message from the server to the browser telling it that the data it's sending is of a certain type (`text/plain` with UTF-8 encoding in this case), and the browser should interpret the data as such. The way the data is eventually displayed is up to the browser, but the browser should assume the `Content-Type` is correct rather than looking at the extension (which may not even exist in a URL) or trying to analyse the data. In other words, it should treat all `text/plain` the same way.

Firefox is only doing what the server tells it to do. The server is response is incorrect (we are currently making the assumption that this is really supposed to be an image - correct in this case, but not *all* cases, hence why browsers cannot reliably detect this).

If you really want, you can save the image and open it in an image viewer. You could also install [an addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/force-content-type/) to force any URL that ends in `.jpeg` to be rendered as an image - but do note that this may break other things.

At the end of the day, the server is doing the wrong thing - and, as far as web standards go, FF is doing the right thing by listening to it.

---

Note that RFC 2616 says:

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a
>      Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If
>      and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
>      recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
>      content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
>      resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
>      treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

The more recent replacement RFC 2731 notes that some browsers guess anyway, but this is not recommended:

> In practice, resource owners do not always properly configure their
>      origin server to provide the correct Content-Type for a given
>      representation, with the result that some clients will examine a
>      payload's content and override the specified type.  Clients that do
>      so risk drawing incorrect conclusions, which might expose additional
>      security risks (e.g., "privilege escalation").  Furthermore, it is
>      impossible to determine the sender's intent by examining the data
>      format: many data formats match multiple media types that differ only
>      in processing semantics.  Implementers are encouraged to provide a
>      means of disabling such "content sniffing" when it is used.

The issue is that any arbitrary data stream might *look like* a JPEG by extension or by contents, but if the source does not *intend* for it to be an image, then interpreting it as such would be wrong. When a `Content-Type` is provided, browsers should trust the server to know what it's doing and interpret the data as the header specifies.

Comment: But there's no problem with the image(https://s.yimg.com/hd/answers/i/7f86761175b34edab6be4165401163c9_A.png?a=answers&mr=0&x=1419441468&s=f9543010953b94ce5c2e0883d66c1d78) in Torch.

Comment: @RogUE Browser implementations vary. None are strictly conforming to standards. And standards change over time as well. At the end of the day, Firefox's behaviour in this instance is fully valid, perhaps *more* valid than what Torch does, and the reason for this behaviour is the server is doing something wrong. When one half of a communication throws out incorrect garbage, you cannot expect the communication to continue successfully - whether it ends up succeeding or failing would be down to luck.

Comment: So, it's a fault from the server side?

Comment: @RogUE Yes. The server is telling Firefox that this set of bytes is text encoded as UTF-8. Firefox proceeds to take its default action for text. Torch, based on Chromium, decides to do its own detection of what the data is based on magic numbers - which is helpful in this case, but note that this actually causes incorrect behaviour in some other cases.

Comment: @RogUE I don't use Yahoo Answers. "Bob" is not exactly an uncommon name.

Comment: Sorry about that.